# How to check file name with regular expression in linux shell sript

Tags: regex, linux, shell

Let me know that suitable regular expression to check the following file names in linux shell script.

```
VMHOST_YYYYMMDD_CPU.csv
VMHOST_YYYYMMDD_MEM.csv
VMHOST_YYYYMMDD_DISK.csv
VMHOST_YYYYMMDD_NET.csv
VMOS_YYYYMMDD_CPU.csv
VMOS_YYYYMMDD_MEM.csv
VMOS_YYYYMMDD_DISK.csv
VMOS_YYYYMMDD_NET.csv
```

I tried like this:

```
if [[ $filename == [VMHOST|VMOS][_][0-9]{8}[_][CPU|MEM|DISK|NET][.]csv ]]; then
        echo "$filename"
fi
```

But it does not work.
So could anybody help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extended pattern matching:

```
shopt -s extglob  ## Required if Bash is earlier than 4.1.
[[ $filename == @(VMHOST|VMOS)_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_@(CPU|MEM|DISK|NET).csv ]] || echo "== $filename failed."
```

Or simply use regex:

```
[[ $filename =~ (VMHOST|VMOS)_[0-9]{8}_(CPU|MEM|DISK|NET)[.]csv ]]
```

If Bash is earlier than 4.0, you need to store it on a variable:

```
re='(VMHOST|VMOS)_[0-9]{8}_(CPU|MEM|DISK|NET)[.]csv'
[[ $filename =~ $re ]]
```

With extended pattern matching, you can skip testing and just expand the files that you only need:

```
shopt -s extglob
for filename in @(VMHOST|VMOS)_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_@(CPU|MEM|DISK|NET).csv; do
    echo "$filename"
done
```

Test:

```
#!/bin/bash

names=(VMHOST_00000000_CPU.csv VMHOST_00000000_MEM.csv VMHOST_00000000_DISK.csv VMHOST_00000000_NET.csv VMOS_00000000_CPU.csv VMOS_00000000_MEM.csv VMOS_00000000_DISK.csv VMOS_00000000_NET.csv)

re='(VMHOST|VMOS)_[0-9]{8}_(CPU|MEM|DISK|NET)[.]csv'
for filename in "${names[@]}"; do
    [[ $filename == @(VMHOST|VMOS)_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_@(CPU|MEM|DISK|NET).csv ]] && echo "$filename (extglob ok)"
    [[ $filename =~ $re ]] && echo "$filename (regex ok)"
    echo
done
```

Output:

```
VMHOST_00000000_CPU.csv (extglob ok)
VMHOST_00000000_CPU.csv (regex ok)

VMHOST_00000000_MEM.csv (extglob ok)
VMHOST_00000000_MEM.csv (regex ok)

VMHOST_00000000_DISK.csv (extglob ok)
VMHOST_00000000_DISK.csv (regex ok)

VMHOST_00000000_NET.csv (extglob ok)
VMHOST_00000000_NET.csv (regex ok)

VMOS_00000000_CPU.csv (extglob ok)
VMOS_00000000_CPU.csv (regex ok)

VMOS_00000000_MEM.csv (extglob ok)
VMOS_00000000_MEM.csv (regex ok)

VMOS_00000000_DISK.csv (extglob ok)
VMOS_00000000_DISK.csv (regex ok)

VMOS_00000000_NET.csv (extglob ok)
VMOS_00000000_NET.csv (regex ok)
```

Comment: `[[ $filename =~ (VMHOST|VMOS)_[0-9]{8}_(CPU|MEM|DISK|NET)[.] csv ]` work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
if [[ $f =~ (VMHOST|VMOS)_[0-9]{8}_(CPU|MEM|DISK|NET)\.csv ]]
  then
    echo $f
fi
```

see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/iT3kE7/1)